# How to recover a measure from its Fourier transform?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, integration, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be the complex function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by 
$$
f(t)=\frac{1-it}{1+it}.
$$

1) Does there exist a complex bounded measure $\mu \in M(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\hat{\mu}=f$ (where $\hat{}$ denotes the Fourier transform)?

2) If the answer is positive, do we have $||\mu||\leq 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions... Write ${\displaystyle \frac{1 -it}{1 + it} = 1 - \frac{2}{1 + t^2}  - 2i\frac{t}{1 + t^2}}$. Using the Fourier inversion formula you can find the inverse Fourier transform of ${\displaystyle \frac{1}{1 + t^2}}$ and ${\displaystyle \frac{t}{1 + t^2}}$. (They're actually pretty well known too.) The inverse Fourier transform of $1$ can be expressed in terms of the delta function, so you can get the inverse Fourier transform of ${\displaystyle \frac{1 -it}{1 + it}}$ in this fashion.

Comment: But getting the inverse Fourier transform of the function isn’t the same as finding a suitable measure $\mu$, is it?